# Sending e-mails with Google Web Toolkit?

Tags: email, gwt, smtp, imap, pop3

I have a GWT app, with only client side. How can I send an email with this?
If it's possible please write a short example! Thanks.

Comment: It's the same as sending email through javascript ... How would you do that ?...

Comment: You could use "mailto:" links perhaps?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to send the email from server side. It's almost impossible to compile the required code on the client side.

Regards,
Rodolfo